Classical Mechanics problem involving psuedo force
The problem i am trying to solve is as follows

I decided to solve the problem using fictious forces as the large block would be accelerating.
Suppose the large block is accelrating towards the right with an acceleration of $a$,
the perpendicular to the plane for mass $M$ is,
$$N_1 + Ma\sin\theta = Mg\cos\theta$$
For mass $m$ the equation is,
$$N_2 = ma\sin\theta + mg\cos\theta$$
The equation for the block as a whole is as follows,
$$N_1 \sin\theta = N_2\sin\theta + (m+M)a$$
Solving these 3 equations leads to the following expression for acceleration of the large block,
$$a = \frac{g\sin\theta \cos\theta(M-m)}{(M+m)\sin^2\theta}$$
Since the small mass $m$ must slide upwards,
$$ma\cos\theta \geq mg\sin\theta$$
solving this inequality leads to the answer that,
$$m \leq \frac{M(\cos(2\theta)-1))}{2}$$
However the answer in my book is given to be,
$$m \leq M\cos2\theta$$
One thing i noticed is that equating $N_1 = N_2$ does yeild the answer in the textbook however i do not understand why they would be equal, any help would be highly appreciated.
I believe i am making a mistake in some concept of fictious forces, could someone please see where i am going wrong.

You might be making a mistake with free body diagrams. Try drawing the forces.

I drew them multiple times and was getting the same answer, thats why i posted it here!
